# Load balancing Sonatype Nexus running on Tomcat Server

Tags: linux, maven, tomcat, nexus, sonatype

We are trying to create a High Availability (HA) Nexus environment for the [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)/[CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) space.

I have two Linux boxes and a common share file mount on top of these. Each of the Linux boxes, I have a Tomcat running with the `nexus.war` inside it. Both the Nexus wars would point to the same `sonatype-work` directory to keep the artifacts in sync.

I would be creating load balanced [virtual IP (VIP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_IP_address) in a [round-robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) fashion for the two Linux boxes. Any better approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues:

- you should not be using Tomcat to run the Nexus Repository Manager, but instead of the bundled Jetty server
- you can NOT have two Nexus Repository Manager instances accessing the same storage at the same time, but you can use this for active/standby type setup (see https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465118)

For a HA setup with Nexus you would instead multiple servers running in parallel. Check out the deployment guidelines for more detail. http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/downloads/the-nexus-professional-deployment-guidelines/

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @ManfredMoser. Appreciate your comment. I am not sure whether I would be able to move away from tomcat. Rest of the changes are easily doable.